# Mirroring Parse Database Locally iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, datastore, mirror

What is the best way to mirror parse's database locally?

I am aware of the Local DataStore https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#local-datastore BUT the description states "You can use this for data that doesn't need to be saved to the cloud, but this is especially useful for temporarily storing data so that it can be synced later."

Is there an easier way to ensure anything that you save to parse is also pinned to the device?

Comment: Did you scroll down to the "Pinning" section of the guide you linked?

Comment: Why does your device need everything? And how should the device know when something changed on the server?